Understanding correct parameters while creating alerts for Azure
I came across a code and want to implement the same for my pipeline for vm availability metrics, but not able to understand usage of -windowsize and -frequency parameters they are used as below :
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "VM CPU Percentage Exceeded- $machinename " -ResourceGroupName $RGroupName -WindowSize 0:5 -Frequency 0:5 -TargetResourceScope $virtualMachine -TargetResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TargetResourceRegion "westeurope" -Description $ciNumber -Severity "2" -ActionGroupId $actionId -Condition $triggerCondition1

where we have declared $RGroupname, $actionId and $triggerCondition1 at the top in the code.
What is Windowsize and Frequency implying here?


What is Window size and Frequency implying here?

-windowsSize & -Frequency are one of the main parameters used along with the Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 command.
-WindowsSize parameter defines the time interval within which the system evaluates the metric to trigger the alert. Below I have used "0:5" as window size so it means that 5 minutes. In your example, If the average CPU percentage over the last 5 minutes exceeds the threshold defined in the variable $Condition, the alert will trigger.
-Frequencyparameter means the frequency of evaluating the alert condition during the specified timeframe of -window Size. As I mentioned above,"0:5" indicates a 5-minute interval.
For example, if we take the same example as above, the average CPU percentage is calculated every 5 minutes within the last 5-minute window, results in a total window of 5 minutes with calculations occurring every 5 minutes within that window.
I have tried to create and trigger a sample alert rule with all the required parameters as shown below.
$criteria = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "Availability" -TimeAggregation average -Operator lessthan 
-Threshold xxx
$actiongroup = [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models.ActivityLogAlertActionGroup]::New("/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/jahresources/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/newgr")
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "newlaertrule"  `
-ResourceGroupName "jahresources" `
-WindowSize 0.5 `
-Frequency 0.1 `
-condition $criteria `
-ActionGroup $actiongroup `
-Severity 3 `
-TargetResourceId "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/jahresources/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/jahresources94bf"




Reference: Add-azmetricalertrulev2 Parameters
